# ConvertAPI DOCX to PDF, want MS Word style comments in margins

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, convertapi

I want to convert DOCX files to PDF using ConvertAPI. When a .DOCX is saved as a .PDF in Word O365, the comments are output in the right margin.

I am aware that the comments can be converted to PDF notes but this is not what I'd like.

```py
convertapi.api_secret = '<mykey>'
result = convertapi.convert('pdf', {'File': '<URL>', 
                                    'Converter':'Printer', 
                                    'ConvertComments': 'true'
                                    }, from_format = 'docx')
result.file.save(r'<Location>')
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Add 'converter':'printer' parameter to enable 'ConvertComments': 'true'

Comment: Tomas, I edited my code above to reflect this and the actual code I'm testing but the output did not change.

Comment: I suggest to contact support directly and send your files to show them what is wrong.  From your current explanation, it is hard to understand what is wrong and what you want to fix.

Comment: The website pointed me to SO for support. Regardless, I just decided to use a different API (Zamzar). Which solved this.